# Dynamically choosing the close effect on a jquery-ui-dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using this dialog:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    hide: {effect: "fade", duration: 3000},
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            $.post(someurl, function() {
                $("#myDialog").dialog( "close" );
            });
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

I have two close actions that are different semantically:

1. Close after success - in this case I want to slowly fade out the dialog (I'm also displaying a green Vee icon, not shown in the above code snippet).
2. Close after cancel - I would like to immediately make the dialog disappear, the fade effect doesn't fit here IMO.

The above code just uses `.dialog("close")` in both cases, so of course both cases get the same fade out effect.

What's the best way to achieve instant close on the second case, while retaining the slow fadeout in the first?

**Edit**: I also want clicking ESCAPE to have the exact same effect as the Cancel button - instant fade out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    hide: null,
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "hide", "fade").dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function(e) {
        $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "hide", null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even know you can set options after the dialog is created. I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: Clicking ESCAPE this fades out slowly. Any idea of to change that behavior?

Comment: Yep, I've updated my answer. Simply, set hide handler to false and just change to fade after clicking "Save" button. Resetting hide option to false in close event handler is necessary, so that if you open the same dialog again, the behavior will be the same as on first open.

Comment: BTW, the default for `hide:` is `null`, not `false`.

Comment: Yeah, I know - but I guess `null` might be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the hide option in both case:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "hide", "fade").dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "hide", null).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("option", "hide", false);
        }
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/yJ96r/)**

Comment: How would you make pressing ESCAPE not have the fade out effect?

Comment: You can use the `beforeClose` event and change the hide option is the ESC key was pressed

Answer (score 0):

For your "Close after success" case you could just issue 
    $('.ui-dialog').fadeOut(5000);

This is how I used the above:

```
$('input').keypress(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") { //works on 1st char you type
        $('.ui-dialog').fadeOut(5000); 
    }
});
```

Also, instead of just open, you'd need: 
    myDlg.dialog('close').dialog('open');