# How to make jquery-ui-dialog not have a close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I didn't find this [in the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options).

Should I just make the close button `display:none` with css, or is there a clean way in the API to make a dialog without the X button (top-right)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible to toggle via parameters. It makes no sense to provide dialogs without closing buttong/possibility. This wouldn't be good for usability reasons. If you need this for design purposes it's okay to do this via CSS.

Comment: @Smamatti - the dialog is part of a wizard, where there's one way to proceed - and simply closing the dialog is not an option at this point.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093486/dynamically-choosing-the-close-effect-on-a-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896777/remove-close-button-on-jqueryui-dialog

Comment: @BarryChapman - wtf? No it really isn't.

Comment: But @Chris is right. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to disable the 'X' button. You would need to add css to display none/hide() the element with the class 'ui-icon-closethick' when it is loaded and opened.

Comment: I'll just apply the css statically via `dialogClass:foo`

Answer (score 6):

This may solve your Problem:

```
       $("#dialogId").dialog({
           closeOnEscape: false,
           open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .hide() did not work for me. This did:

```
$('#divMsg').dialog({ title: 'Please wait...',
                      modal: true,
                      closeOnEscape: false,
                      open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).css('display', 'none'); } }).text('Text To Display').css('background', 'white');
```

This code snippet also shows how to set the title and text of the dialog box -- I am using it as a modal notification window and closing it when my AJAX call completes.